# disable touch on Child SKEmitterNode

Tags: touch, parent-child, skspritenode, skemitternode, child-nodes

i create a SKSpriteNode with an Emitter as Child

```
onObject: SKSpriteNode! = SPSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture)
onObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ballSize / 2) * 0.99)
        onObject.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        onObject.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        onObject.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        onObject.physicsBody?.mass = 3
        onObject.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1
        onObject.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = ballRotation
        onObject.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(ballRotation)
        onObject.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5

        let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "emitter.sks")
        particles?.zPosition = onObject.zPosition - 1
        particles?.particleZPosition = onObject.zPosition - 1
        particles?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        particles?.targetNode = self
        particles?.particlePositionRange.dx = onObject.size.width
        particles?.particlePositionRange.dy = onObject.size.height
        particles?.name = "particles"
        particles?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        onObject.addChild(particles!)
```

but if i touch the emitter, the action will be triggered even if the userinteraction is disabled?!

how could i fix it?

i already tried to ignore the touched.name (particles) but it doesn't seem to work because every time i touch the particles or anywhere near it, the parent node will also get the touch event.

how could i prevent this?

im checking the Touch Event in

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
let touch = touches.first!

        let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: positionInScene)
        print(touchedNode.name)
if ((touchedNode.name?.range(of: powerUps.POWERUPS)) != nil){
                    print("powerUp Touched")
                }
}
```